# How to animate in half circle only

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to be able to animate in half circle then animation would be trigger only when I am at the exact div so it will not animate when viewing in other section. The circle path is already define in CSS and I could not change it all I can put maybe is put an overlay circle on top of the arc? So with this parameter I am thinking jquery would be a good approach or what do you think? I am new to animation with curb so I hope you can help me. Below is the illustration and the code that I have tried.

[image]

```
function moveit() {
t += 0.05;

var r = 100;         // radius
var xcenter = 100;   // center X position
var ycenter = 100;   // center Y position

var newLeft = Math.floor(xcenter + (r * Math.cos(t)));
var newTop = Math.floor(ycenter + (r * Math.sin(t)));

$('#circgreen').animate({
    top: newTop,
    left: newLeft,
}, 1, function() {
     moveit();//
})
```

}

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  moveit();
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. I don't think I'd try to calculate the circle's arc and animate along it using JavaScript.

Since the outer circle is defined in CSS, I'd define the green overlaying circle as an inner element, whose absolute position is relative to the outer circle. Then just rotate the outer circle:

```js
$('button').click(() => {
 $('#circle').toggleClass('rotated')
})
```

```css
body {
 overflow: hidden; // just to make the example cleaner
}

#circle {
 border: 1px solid #999;
 border-radius: 200px;
 position: relative;
 height: 400px;
 width: 400px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}

#circle.rotated {
 transform: rotate(135deg);
}

#circle::after {
 background: green;
 border-radius: 5px;
 content: '';
 height: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 10px;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click to Rotate</button>
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: can I have a follow question about this? I would like to ask on how to do this  be responsive design? because on other screen size this size break. thanks

Comment: @propaganja It depends, but all you you would need to grow/shrink is the big outer circle. Setting the height/width of `#circle` to dynamic values (e.g. `%` or `vw`) and giving them a fixed max height/width and possibly a fixed min height/width would make this responsive. Here's a JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/87rt9j32/

Comment: Thank you again! you hit it again!